# How to implement Reuse Component in UI5?

Tags: sapui5

I would like to use [Classification](https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/#/detail/Apps('F2189')/S9OP) component in my ui5 app.

The structure of the component looks as following:

[image]

I would like to pickup the classification component. The content of the `Component-dbg.js` looks as following:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
    "sap/suite/ui/generic/template/extensionAPI/ReuseComponentSupport",
    "sap/suite/ui/generic/template/extensionAPI/UIMode",
    "sap/i2d/lo/lib/vchclf/common/Constants",
    "sap/i2d/lo/lib/vchclf/components/classification/service/ClassificationService"
], function(UIComponent, ReuseComponentSupport, UIMode, Constants, ClassificationService) {
    "use strict";

    /**
     * Classification Component.
     * @class ClassificationComponent
     * @extends sap.ui.core.UIComponent
     */
    return UIComponent.extend("sap.i2d.lo.lib.vchclf.components.classification.Component", {
        metadata: {
            manifest: "json",
            properties: {
                uiMode: {
                    type: "string",
                    group: "standard",
                    defaultValue: "Display"
```

I would like to use it in my app and tried to bind in `manifest` file as following:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "minUI5Version": "1.30.0",
        "libs": {
            "sap.ui.layout": {},
            "sap.ui.core": {},
            "sap.m": {}
        },
        "components": {
            "sap.i2d.lo.lib.vchclf.components.classification": {}
        }
    },
    "componentUsages": {
        "classcomponent": {
            "name": "sap.i2d.lo.lib.vchclf.components.classification"
        }
    },
```

and I've got the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: failed to load 'sap/i2d/lo/lib/vchclf/components/classification/Component.js' from ../../resources/sap/i2d/lo/lib/vchclf/components/classification/Component.js: 404 - Not Found
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I also tried:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="ch.mindustrie.CLASSIFICATION.controller.App" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <App id="idAppControl">
        <pages>
            <Page title="{i18n>title}">
                <content>
                    <core:ComponentContainer id="classificationComponentContainer" name="sap.i2d.lo.lib.vchclf.components.classification" propagateModel="true"/>
                </content>
            </Page>
        </pages>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

and also got error message: 
[image]